# Splitting two large CSV files preserving relations between file A and B across the resulting files

Tags: file, csv, awk, split

I have TWO large, CSV files (around 1GB). They both share relation between each other (ID is lets say like a foreign key). Structure is simple, line by line *but CSV cells with a line break in the value string can appear*

37373;"SOMETXT-CRCF or other other line break-";3838383;"sasa ssss"

One file is P file and other is T file. T is like 70% size of the P file (P > T). I must cut them to smaller parts since they are to big for the program I have to import them... I can not simply use `split -l 100000` since I will loose ID=ID relations which must be preserved! Relation can be  1:1, 2:3, 4:6 or 1:5. So stupid file splitting is no option, we must check the place where we create a new file. This is example with simplified CSV structure and a place where I want the file to be cut (and the lines above go to separate P|T__00x file and we continue till P or T ends). Lines are sorted in both files, so no need to search for IDs across whole file!

**File "P" (empty lines for clearness):**

```
CSV_FILE_P;HEADER;GOES;HERE
564788402;1;1;"^";"01"
564788402;2;1;"^";"01"
564788402;3;1;"^";"01"

575438286;1;1;"^";"01"
575438286;1;1;"^";"01"
575438286;2;1;"37145859"
575438286;2;1;"37145859"
575438286;3;1;"37145859"
575438286;3;1;"37145859"

575439636;1;1;"^"
575439636;1;1;"^"

# lets say ~100k line limit of file P is somewhere here and no more 575439636 ID lines , so we cut.

575440718;1;1;"^"
575440718;1;1;"^"
575440718;2;1;"10943890"
575440718;2;1;"10943890"
575440718;3;1;"10943890"
575440718;3;1;"10943890"

575441229;1;1;"^";"01"
575441229;1;1;"^";"01"
575441229;2;1;"4146986"
575441229;2;1;"4146986"
575441229;3;1;"4146986"
575441229;3;1;"4146986"
```

**File T (empty lines for clearness)**

```
CSV_FILE_T;HEADER;GOES;HERE
564788402;4030000;1;"0204"

575438286;6102000;1;"0408"
575438286;6102000;0;"0408"
575439636;7044010;1;"0408"
575439636;7044010;0;"0408"

# we must cut here since bigger file "P" 100k limit has been reached
# and we end here because 575439636 ID lines are over.

575440718;6063000;1;"0408"
575440718;6063000;0;"0408"

575441229;8001001;0;"0408"
575441229;8001001;1;"0408"
```

Can you please help splitting those two files into many 100 000 (or so) lines separate files T_001 and corresponding P_001 file and so on? So ID matches between file parts. I believe awk will be the best tool but I have not got much experience in this field. And the last thing - CSV header should be preserved in each of the files.
I have powerful AIX machine to cope with that (linux also possible since AIX commands are limited sometimes)

Comment: Why does a powerful AIX machine needs to get trashed with that? CSV is obviously not the right data format for the solution. Use a database

Comment: Yes but I am not DB administrator to create, import, use JOIN and then export again DB solution. I need awk, tail, head or other tools solution. Program that needs those smaller files imports from CSV files and this is my goal - get many 100 000 lines files with relations preserved.

Comment: man... I work in a big IT company and I can not create and administrate DB myself. DB guy is on his vacations and the work must be done by tomorrow. So stackoverflow community is my last hope.

Comment: Does it matter if the empty lines are just removed ?

Comment: We do not need then at all (empty lines are for you to see relations on the first glance, I have entered them). We might have a CRLF (or maybe other) line break at a vary CSV "cell" so between quotes - this makes a new empty line sometimes in a CSV... but so far I have spotted only one place with such "bad data" (since this filed is a person name - no white chars in names in our country :) ...). I can remove this issue manual.

Comment: I'm finding it a little difficult to understand the layout. You say number;text;number;text at the start but the example doesn't do that. And the number of fields is changing. But if you mean cut when the ID at the beginning changes, then yes, that's doable. Putting a CRLF in the middle isn't helpful though!

Comment: The sample you have posted either has unmatched or extremely inconsistent quotes

Comment: CSV in the example might be broken (I will fix it in a minute)!
ID is the first "column", I have removed many personal data from the CSV to make an example. Sorry if quotes are broken, do not bother.

CRLF in a middle - I have found only one place with such issue. I can fix the source file myself before processing though!

Comment: It's fine. You can cut from the first ; to make the ID. I'll put up a quick example to give you an idea. I'm wondering about the CRLF though - if you have to count quotes or semicolons, it makes it trickier...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parse the beginning IDs with awk and then check to see if the current ID is the same as the last one. Only when it is different are you allowed close the current output file and open a new one. At that point record the ID for tracking the next file. You can track this id in a text file or in memory. I've done it in memory but with big files like this you could run into trouble. It's easier to keep track in memory than opening multiple files and reading from them.

Then you just need to distinguish between the first file (output and recording) and the second file (output and using the prerecorded data).

The code does a very brute force check on the possibility of a CRLF in a field - if the line does not begin with what looks like an ID, then it outputs the line and does no further testing on it. Which is a problem if the CRLF is followed immediately by a number and semicolon! This might be unlikely though...

Run with: gawk -f parser.awk P T

I don't promise this works!

```
BEGIN {
    MAXLINES = 100000
    block = 0
    trackprevious = 0
}


FNR == 1 {
    # First line is CSV header
    csvheader = $0

    if (FILENAME == "-")
    {
        _error = 1
        print "Error: Need filename on command line"
        exit 1
    }

    if (trackprevious)
    {
        _error = 1
        print "Only one file can track another"
        exit 1
    }

    if (block >= 1)
    {
        # New file - track previous output...
        close(outputname)
        Tracking[block] = idval

        print "Output for " FILENAME " tracks previous file"
        trackprevious = 1
    }
    else
    {
        print "Chunking output (" MAXLINES ") for " FILENAME
    }

    linecount = 0
    idval = 0
    block = 1

    outputprefix = FILENAME "_block"
    outputname = sprintf("%s_%03d", outputprefix, block)

    print csvheader > outputname
    next
}


/^[0-9]+;/ {
    linecount++

    newidval = $0
    sub(/;.*$/, "", newidval)
    newidval = newidval + 0     # make a number

    startnewfile = 0

    if (trackprevious && (idval != newidval) && (idval == Tracking[block]))
    {
        startnewfile = 1
    }
    else if (!trackprevious && (idval != newidval) && (linecount > MAXLINES))
    {
        # Last ID value found before new file:
        Tracking[block] = idval
        startnewfile = 1
    }

    if (startnewfile)
    {
        close(outputname)
        block++

        outputname = sprintf("%s_%03d", outputprefix, block)
        print csvheader > outputname
        linecount = 1
    }

    print $0 > outputname
    idval = newidval
    next
}

{
    linecount++
    print $0 > outputname
}
```

Comment: Caught one error in the second sprintf (misspelled!) but it seems to work ok!

Comment: thank you, I did not test it yet. But this looks like smart (~100k) line per file hack (not loosing any records across one part file) but what about file T? It should be splitted at the same time in a such way to cover all ID=ID records from the P_block_xxx file (corresponding ID lines from T should be placed at T_block_xxx to make a usable file pair). We do not need to search for data in T file, it is sorted (as in example).
 The import program expects TWO, P and T files to be imported at once.

Comment: Yeah, I was just reading back over the original post and I see that. It doesn't keep the header either (easy enough). Are P and T matched? Ie: if there are 100  * "575438286" in P are there also 100 in T? (edit: Relation can be 1:1, 2:3, 4:6 or 1:5. I see. More difficult)

Comment: What you can do is parse P and simultanously generate a tracking file for T. Then parse T. Or you can open P and open T and scan them both at the same time. As the IDs are sorted, that is just as easy. I'll come back to you :-)

Comment: Yup if 100 ID where in both files the simple `split` would be enough and I would not ask anyone how to do that. But now I would use tail -n 1 and head -n1 to get first & last P_block_ ID and then hmm dunno grep to count the first ID occurrence in big T file, then grep to get last occurrence of the last ID and then tail + head combined to cut the wanted section into the new > T_block_xxx. Not awk but bash style... T file looks like sorted so no need to crawl and search for corresponding IDs! Just search for beginning and search for last occurrence line and then cut this section and viola!

Comment: Yes, you could it that way! I like doing these things in awk myself!

Comment: Tried a quick tracking section which tracks the previous numbers in an array in memory. When the second file, T, is opened, it uses the tracking information instead of generating it.

Comment: I will not beat about the bush, you are the man, script does work like a charm and I did improve it a bit to suite my needs. Data is complete and well distributed between files. I did `cat *P_block* |wc -l` and `cat P |wc -l` to check if all lines are there and the result was x+70 since I got 71 files ( 70 more cvs headers). Quick tail 001 +head 002 also did nt reveal any bugs (or not yet lol). Yeah, you made my day! Thank you so much. Cheers!

Comment: Cool! Glad it worked. Accept the answer if it worked out ok ;-)

Comment: OK, I am new here so I head to find that option. Thank you once again!